# Rails - filter datetime for time only in joined model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have two models: `Route` **has_many** `Details`

In a controller I join the two models as follow:

```
@routes = Route.where("origin_city_name LIKE (?)", "%#{@from}")
                   .destination_city_name(@to)
                   .company(@company)
                   .joins(:details)
```

`Detail` has a `departure` datetime attribute.

I'm able to filter by `date` as follow:

```
@routes = @routes.where( details: { departure: @date..Float::INFINITY }) if params[:date]
```

How can I do the same for `time` only?

Comment: You mean only the time part of the `departure`?

Comment: yes please, only time part

Comment: You can get the time part of a column in pg with `details.departure::time` and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgresql query will be like this:

```
@routes.where("departure::time > ?", '13:20:00')
```

Comment: can't test it right now.. but, are you sure this will work even if departure is a column of details?

Comment: You may specify table in the query: @routes.where("details.departure::time > ?", '13:20:00'). But it should work without table too unless i have only one `departure` column in your query.